# Match multiple value to another table's multiple value if match any value than return raw in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table that name are job_post and snapshot.Here these table looks like below :

1)snapshot table

[image]

2)jobpost table

[image]

Here I have attached two table.I want to match snapshot skill with jobpost skill (**Note:** Here in skill column there are numeric value that stored skill id form the skill table).If any skill id match than return jobpost details.

So what query should I have to write?

Comment: Consider normalising your table. You should probably have a linking table to connect your skills to job_post, and skills to snapshot

Comment: `skill_id` is separated by a comma `,`?

Comment: @reno yes skill_id is separated by  **( , )**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that `skill_id` is separated by a comma `,`, try this;)

```
select t1.* 
from job_post t1 
inner join snapshot t2 on t2.skill regexp replace(t1.skill, ',', '|') group by t1.job_id
```

Hope works for you.

Comment: Because, I got same record twice.

Comment: @Nisarg `replace(t1.skill, ',', '|')` will get you `skill_id` separated by `|` like '1|2|3', then `t2.skill regexp '1|2|3'` will get you record that `t2.skill` included '1' or '2' or '3'. Check some reference [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html).